# CakePHP filter list by slug instead of ID

Tags: php, database, url, cakephp, slug

I'm using CakePHP, this is the structure of my DB:

```
CarMakes
----------------------------------
ID     Slug     Name
16     ford     Ford

CarModels
----------------------------------
ID     Name     CarMake_ID
10     Escort   16

Cars
----------------------------------
ID     Name     CarModel_ID
1      My car   10
```

I want to view a list of cars by CarMakes.Slug

so the url would be:
http://localhost/cars/ford

Any ideas or general directions of information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`findBy()`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1026/findBy) or [`findAllBy()`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1025/findAllBy) to retrieve records based on something other than ID. If you need to supply conditions to the query, use regular [`find()`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1018/find):

```
$this->Car->find(
   'all',
   array(
      'conditions' => array(
         'CarMake.Slug' => $slug,
         'Car.Name LIKE' => $name
      ),
   )
);
```

Also, for the URL you're trying to set up, you will need to create a [route](http://book.cakephp.org/view/945/Routes-Configuration) for `/cars`:

```
Router::connect(
   '/cars/:make',
   array('controller' => 'cars', 'action' => 'bymake'),
   array(
      'pass' => array('make'),
      'make' => '[A-Za-z]+'
   )
);
```

**Edit:**

The above works if your conditions are based on a direct association on your model. If your conditions are on a recursive association (i.e. Car->CarModel->CarMake), you need to use explicit joins:

```
$result = $this->Car->find('all', array(
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'car_models',
            'type' => 'inner',
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions' => array('car_models.id = Car.car_model_id')
        ),
        array(
            'table' => 'car_makes',
            'type' => 'inner',
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions' => array(
                'car_makes.id = car_models.car_make_id',
                'car_makes.slug' => $slug
            )
        )
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
        'Car.name LIKE' => $name
    )
));
```

Comment: Thanks so much for going to the effort of writing that out for me, I'll give that a go.

Comment: I gave this a go last night, I see what it's doing now but I'm getting this SQL error:

`SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'CarMake.Slug' in 'where clause' [CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 684]

Comment: Do you have the association between Car and CarMake defined in your model?

Comment: No only Car and CarModel, there isn't really a direct relationship between them:
`
 var $belongsTo = array(
  'Carmodel' => array(
   'className' => 'Carmodel',
   'foreignKey' => 'carmodel_id',
   'conditions' => '',
   'fields' => '',
   'order' => ''
  )
 );

Comment: See updated answer that addresses conditions on recursive relationships.

Comment: Excellent! That worked, thank you so much. I just need to figure how to paginate (previously `$this->set('cars', $this->paginate());`) the results now and I'm all set.